# Could these be the seedlings of poisonous plants?

Tags: seedlings, growth, poison-ivy

I brought my plants in last fall to keep ‘em from the winter weather. In January, I noticed a few seedlings growing in my pineapple planter. I let them grow since they didnt look like common weeds. When their true leaves started to really show, I really thought they were strawberries. I spilled strawberry seeds into the bag-soil.
Recently, I transplanted the seedlings into their own container when i started taking my plants outdoor. These days, I’m not so sure what they are anymore[image] Sure don't look like strawberry plants.
Google said they might be poison oak or cannabis. I very much doubt it, though, because I haven't been around those two plants.
But, are they???
Thank you so much for taking the time to read my question. I live in South Carolina, by the way.

Comment: They're definitely not cannabis, and I doubt that they're poison oak, which grows as three leaflets, not individual leaves.

Answer (score 1):

These look rather like Roselle (*Hibiscus sabdariffa*) - early leaves are highly variable and there is a tell-tale redness extending into the leaf main vein. If it is roselle you should see the leaf shape change quite a bit as the plant grows with deep clefts between leaf lobes. I'd say it was worth hanging on to these seedlings until they reveal themselves categorically, roselle produces a nice tea in a hot growing environment.

Definitely not cannabis or strawberry or poison ivy or poison oak due to leaf shape but the bronzing of the young leaves, which can happen in poison ivy or roselle, can be misleading in that respect.

Comment: I don't think it is roselle. The edge pattern is unlike what I have seen.